# Access violation of printing variable

Tags: c++, exception, runtime-error, access-violation

I have the following problem where I will get an access violation exception when trying to print a variable, but only after a loop has run a specific number of times.

Specifically on the 211th iteration, the line:

```
cout << "Frame " << i << ", Recall: " << recall << ", Precision: " << precision << ", IoU: " << iou << endl;
```

Gives the error:

```
 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x3F09C003.
```

The weird thing is, this only occurs if I am printing a variable, and it always occurs at the 211th iteration. If I remove the print statement completely, or even just print a string, it works fine. But if I print any variable (i, recall, precision, etc.), it throws this exception. It will also throw the same exception if I remove the printing from the loop completely, and just have a single print statement outside of the loop. Any suggestions?

Code below:

```
template <typename T>
template <typename T2>
void Rect<T>::GetPerformance(const Rect<T2>& actual, 
              float &iou, float &precision, float &recall) const {
    float numDetections = Area();
    float numActual = actual.Area();
    iou = Overlap(actual);
    float numCorrect = iou *(actual.Area() + Area()) / (1 + iou);

    precision = numCorrect / numDetections;
    recall = numCorrect / numActual;
}

...
In Main
...
Mat frame;
Mat newFrame;
int i = 0;

float recall;
float precision;
float iou;

float avgRecall = 0;
float avgPrecision = 0;
float avgIoU = 0;

while (1)
{
    iFrame = cvQueryFrame(capture); 
    if (!iFrame) break;
    frame = iFrame;

    FloatRect bb = carTracker.Track(frame);

    bb.GetPerformance(gts[i], iou, precision, recall);
    avgRecall += recall;
    avgPrecision += precision;
    avgIoU += iou;
    cout << "Frame " << i << ", Recall: " << recall << ", Precision: " << precision << ", IoU: " << iou << endl;

    i++;
}
```

Comment: More then likely you are going past the end of the data that you have.  What is the size of `gts`?

Comment: Gts is of size 252. This exception always occurs in the "std::cout" line, and only when printing a variable. There are no arrays involved where it fails.

Comment: [Use your debugger](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and break after the 210th time and see what's going on. If you still have trouble then [post a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) , the problem is most likely affected by code you haven't shown.